# Why I'm getting a 500 server response in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to figure out why my web isn't getting crawled by the Google Spider, and when I do a test about the response of the site I see that I'm getting a 500 server response BUT my website is actually working.

My site is http://lacasadelilihostal.com/ and was made in Laravel.

I see another question when said that the problem could be by a JavaScript error but I don't see anyone in my web; and also I changed the permissions of the public folder to 775 but didn't work either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO


Comment: It's not really about SEO. His server is seems to be responding with a 500 not a 200. Still might be off topic and better suited to Server Fault.

That said, I get a 200 OK, not a 500 when I hit the site. Even with JS disabled.

Comment: Check your error logs for any 500 response - both your web server logs and the Laravel logs in app/storage/logs. That'll give you a more specific error message!

Comment: How did you determine that your website was giving a 500 error?

Comment: I checked in Google Webmaster Tools and another SEO tools and i found that for the crawlers is giving to me a 500 Error, i search in the logs and I found why... In the comments I update my answer with the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check my logs and found that i'm getting the error "'Uninitialized string offset: " in this line:

```
`$langcode = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : '';
$langcode = (!empty($langcode)) ? explode(";", $langcode) : $langcode;
$langcode = (!empty($langcode['0'])) ? explode(",", $langcode['0']) : $langcode;
$langcode = (!empty($langcode['0'])) ? explode("-", $langcode['0']) : $langcode;
$langcode = strtolower($langcode[0]);`       `
```

This only happened with crawlers... I remove the last line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact header response of your homepage. I'm taking a little time to digest this information and will come back. In the meantime others can consider this info too:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 17:35:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=76c6f66056ff1828be5ad677b87f9690; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-2013 19:35:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=76c6f66056ff1828be5ad677b87f9690; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-2013 19:35:34 GMT; path=/; httponly
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```