# Fetch as Google 'Unreachable' error

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, server, lamp, google-crawlers

I just pushed a new version of my site to the server. It seems to be working fine, but I'm getting Google crawl errors and when I try to fetch as Google, I get an unreachable error.

Here's the Google bots latest attempt in the access log:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 4753 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Why is it looking for "-"?

The site uses the Laravel framework and is hosted on a Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server at DigitalOcean.

Comment: It's not, it is looking for /, as in GET /  the "-" is probably the referrer field.

Comment: Ah.  Totally missed that.  Thanks.  So any idea why its failing?

Comment: No idea. You would have to look in your error logs rather than your web server log as the web logs don't give you the details of the error.

Comment: The failed googlebot attempts dont create an error on the server.  The Apache error logs show nothing.

Comment: I've added some tags to your question that will hopefully get the attention of those that will know the answer to this.

Comment: Also see a similar question and some answers that may give you some clues.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217623/why-im-getting-a-500-server-response-in-google-webmaster-tools?rq=1

Comment: @revolt_101 Turn debug On in the Larevel app, go to google web master tools and click fetch as google. The displayed content should contain the error, so you can see it. Also you can check laravel log, not apache one for errors.

Comment: Thank you so much shaddy!  Had a look at my Laravel log and found a php error in my locale middleware.  Just tried again and it worked fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: @shaddy You should put that as the answer shaddy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually laravel logs contains most of the error of your app. You can check laravel logs in `storage/logs`, not apache one for errors.